# When I resume a YouTube upload it keeps responding with a 308, so how do I complete the upload?

Tags: curl, file-upload, youtube, youtube-api

I am uploading files to YouTube using the youtube-api fine, using the resumable upload protocol. However, when I try to resume an interrupted upload, and I do the required empty PUT to the upload URL to check the upload status and get the expected 308 response it specifies the range as

`Range: bytes=0-47783737`

So I then PUT the remaining bytes to my upload URL:

`Content-Range: bytes 47783738-48045881/48045882`

`Content-Length: 262144`

This then returned ANOTHER `308` response with the SAME range header. In other words it's ignore my previous PUT and I try again to PUT the remaining bytes of the file. I never get a 201 after going through the resume process.

I am using CURL to make these calls as our software is written in `C++` so the libraries are no help to me.

My curl call when checking the upload status is:

PUT

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer 
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes */48045882

and no body

When I get the 308 http response code back with a Range header of "bytes=0-47783737" then I do this:

PUT

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer 
Content-Length: 262144
Content-Type: video/*
Content-Range: bytes 47783738-48045881/48045882

Where the body of the call is from byte 47783738 of the file until the end of the file.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the [resumable upload protocol](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol); can you show your code ?

Comment: So when I check the upload status, I'm doing a curl call to 

`PUT <UPLOAD_URL_here>

With headers:
Authorization: Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN_here>
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes */48045882

and no body`

When I get the 308 http response code back with a Range header of "bytes=0-47783737" then I do this:

`PUT <UPLOAD_URL_here>

With headers:
Authorization: Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN_here>
Content-Length: 262144
Content-Type: video/*
Content-Range: bytes 47783738-48045881/48045882

Where the body of the call is from byte 47783738 of the file until the end of the file.`